# Possible to create this xml views dynamically in java in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, dynamic

Is it possible to create this XML complex view dynamically on a push of a button using android studio

The output is here :

https://ibb.co/hSkP5k

The XML code is given below

I want to create a button to add this bar dynamically at runtime and want to know whether it is possible..I'm new to android studio and would love some advice on this .

Thanks in advance!

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/forsub1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="50.0dip"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10.0dip"
            android:layout_marginStart="10.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="30.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/round"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"
                android:textSize="40.0sp" />

             <EditText
                android:id="@+id/sub1"
                android:layout_width="170.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:inputType="textCapWords"
                android:paddingStart="10.0dip"
                android:textColor="#ff000000"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_bar"
                android:textSize="30.0sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/present1"
                android:layout_width="50.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/green"
                android:onClick="present"
                android:textSize="15.0sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/absent1"
                android:layout_width="50.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/red"
                android:onClick="absent"
                android:textSize="15.0sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/stats1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/blue_bar"
                android:onClick="stats"
                android:text="0 %"
                android:textSize="15.0sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>**strong text
```

**

Comment: yes, it is possible.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274) Assume that it *is* possible, try it, and if you encounter a problem ask about that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, but don't try with hardcoded widths. Use weights for ease of designing for multiple devices.

Comment: Please see [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question/7274) "Yes or no" isn't all that useful to future readers.